# Print array in sendmail

Tags: php, arrays, forms, function, sendmail

I am trying to echo an array in sendmail's message body. I created a function to print a POST array:

```
function printArray($array, $pad=''){
     foreach (array_slice($array, 3) as $key => $value){
        echo $pad . "$key: $value <br>";
        if(is_array($value)){
            printArray($value, $pad.' ');
        }  
    } 
}
```

It prints perfectly both through print_r

```
printArray($_POST);
```

and if put in a variable

```
$Parray = printArray($_POST);
echo $Parray;
```

But I am not getting it work in sendmail message:

```
$message = printArray($_POST);
mail($to, $subject, print_r($message), $headers);
```

The above code sends email with '1' in message. Cant figure out what am I doing wrong here? since array echoes perfectly, its just the sendmail which does not print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `echo` in the `printArray` function, which sends the data to standard output (so you can see the output on your screen). But if you want to use the result of the function in a variable (like `$message`) you need to return the value from your function.

Since your function is a recursive one (it calls itself), you'll have to collect the output of function calls in a local variable and  then return the accumulated value.

So I'd modify the `printArray()` function to return the constructed message as a string, beside printing it. Something like this:

```
function printArray($array, $pad=''){
    $buffer = array();
     foreach (array_slice($array, 3) as $key => $value){
        $buffer[] = $pad . "$key: $value <br>";
        if(is_array($value)){
            $buffer[] = printArray($value, $pad.' ');
        }
    }
    $output = join('', $buffer);
    echo $output;
    return $output;
}
```

Also as mentioned on other answers, `print_r()` will print the parameter (same as the sample `printArray()` function in the question) but return value is not the printed value unless you pass the second parameter as `true`, which causes `print_r` to return the string value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$value` also may be an `array()`, so you can not echo `$value` directly. Since you checked the value by `is_array()` in `if()` condition, you can place `echo $pad . "$key: $value <br>";` in `else` part. Can try this:

```
function printArray($array, $pad=''){
    foreach (array_slice($array, 3) as $key => $value){        
        if(is_array($value)){
            printArray($value, $pad.' ');
        }else{
            echo $pad . "$key: $value <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

You should not use `print_r($message)` inside `mail()`, Just use the `$message` var instead. Like `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Also you didn't return anything from `printArray()`, so

```
$Parray = printArray($_POST);
echo $Parray;
```

here `echo $Parray;` don't show anything!

In below section

```
$message = printArray($_POST);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

`$message` is `empt()` because `printArray()` don't any thing.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` function return `1` when you have not added second param `TRUE`, if you need buffer output then use 2<sup>nd</sup> param `true` in `print_r` function

```
$message = print_r($_POST, true);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```