# PHP - Send an array with <pre> tags via email

Tags: php, function, email

I've created my first multi-page form using php.

I like the way that the form data can be output using -

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,true).'</pre>';
```

However, instead of printing, I'd like to keep that formatting but have it sent via email using the mail function.

Comment: So create an email and send the printed array. SO is not a **free coding site**

Comment: tried anything? seems trivial

Comment: print_r is usually just for debugging, i would not send it to a user, why not format it all pretty for them.

Comment: sounds like a job for `htmlentities()` / `html_entity_decode()` and the like.

Comment: I found a solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308112/print-array-in-sendmail

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -2):

are you sending it as a html email? because it wont work in plain text

See example 4 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php